# Server error on filling data

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a aspx form where I fill the data. Recently I added a Button and a textbox to the form and wrote the code in Jquery. The problem is that, as soon as I fill the data it works but when I click on Radiobutton or submit the form it gives me the below mentioned error:

"Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Source Error: "

What is the issue,? I enabled the EnableEventValidation=true for checking whether it works or not, but i am still facing the same error.
Please help.

Comment: Can you share the sample code & HTML? I think it is a minor mistake or some conceptual problem.

Comment: Please see the js fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/k7b78sbo/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
  <configuration>    
   <location path="page.aspx">
    <system.web>
     <pages validateRequest="false" />
     <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
   </location>
  </configuration>
```

Add page validation in web.config

Comment: what does page.aspx refer to ?

Comment: I jut put page.aspx as a sample page name.. you can add your page name over there.. sorry for the confusion

Comment: ohkk, let me check and try. will it not effect other page ??

Comment: its giving me Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error

Comment: This is what happening for you
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Use firebug console window to log what you submitting